# What is mean <discount on your next shipment>? is this a rebate for the next shipping cost?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't know exactly what it means :-(

"shipment" indicates item what i order next? or next shipping cost?

really confusing(T_T)

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Yes: the word *next* indicates there's a discount on what you order next. We can't tell what that discount is applied to, but the overall cost of whatever you order and have delivered will be reduced.

Comment: I would take it to mean "order", not "shipping cost".  It's fairly common for companies selling products that you are apt to reorder every month or two to offer some sort of "discount" or "refund" on your "next order", to encourage you to buy from them rather than look for another supplier.

Comment: Could you provide a link to where the sentence occurs?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the phrase is worded badly.  It would have been more clear is they had stated, "discount on your next order". But I think that is what they meant, not based on the grammar but past experience. If they meant the other, they should have said, "discount on the shipping cost of your next order".

Would this product happen to be something you get periodically, such as "Fruit of the Month Club"? If so, that might explain why they are in the mindset of "shipment" rather than "order". To them, you didn't order anything more, you just got part of the next regularly scheduled batch. That doesn't mean their phraseology is clear to others, though.

In the end, it may not matter.  Does it really matter if your $2 discount is applied to the shipping cost or the product? It would matter if the discount is like "10% off". That would amount to $2.50 on a $25 product, but only $0.50 on $5 shipping cost.